# Imported file has a wrong encoding: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4510: character maps to in django import-export

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, django-import-export

I am trying to import data from a csv. Here is the csv's screenshot [image]

as you can see I've imported another csv it was completely ok but. For this csv it's not working. I am getting the error all the time. I am using encoding "utf8"

Here is my code:

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer

url = "https://prowrestling.fandom.com/wiki/New_Japan_Pro_Wrestling/Roster"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# links = [
#     "https://prowrestling.fandom.com/" + a["href"] for a in soup.select("classname a")
# ]
links = [
    "https://prowrestling.fandom.com/" + a["href"] for a in soup.select("td a")
]
with open("real/njpw.csv", 'a', encoding="utf8", newline="") as f:
    print(f)
    wrt = writer(f)
    header = ["ring_name", "height", "weight", "born", "birth_place", "trainer", "debut", "resides"]
    wrt.writerow(header)
    for link in links:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
        ring_name = soup.h2.text.strip()
        height = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Height") + div')
        if height is not None:
            height = height.text.strip()
        else:
            height = ""
        weight = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Weight") + div')
        if weight is not None:
            weight = weight.text.strip()
        else:
            weight = ""
        born = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Born") + div')
        if born is not None:
            born = born.text.strip()
        else:
            born = ""
        birth_place = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Birth Place") + div')
        if birth_place is not None:
            birth_place = birth_place.text.strip()
        else:
            birth_place = ""
        trainer = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Trainer") + div')
        if trainer is not None:
            trainer = trainer.text.strip()
        else:
            trainer = ""
        debut = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Debut") + div')
        if debut is not None:
            debut = debut.text.strip()
        else:
            debut = ""
        resides = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Resides") + div')
        if resides is not None:
            resides = resides.text.strip()
        else:
            resides = ""
        table = [ring_name, height, weight, born, birth_place, trainer, debut, resides]

        wrt.writerow(table)
        print(table)

    #gimmik = soup.select_one('.InformationBoxTitle:-soup-contains("Current gimmick") + div')
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using django-import-export? (it doesn't look like you are).  If not, please modify title and tags for clarity.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

To store data in csv format, you can use padas built-in `to_csv()` method which is super easy.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "https://prowrestling.fandom.com/wiki/New_Japan_Pro_Wrestling/Roster"

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# links = [
#     "https://prowrestling.fandom.com/" + a["href"] for a in soup.select("classname a")
# ]
links = [
    "https://prowrestling.fandom.com/" + a["href"] for a in soup.select("td a")
]
# with open("real/njpw.csv", 'a', encoding="utf8", newline="") as f:
#     print(f)
#     wrt = writer(f)
#     header = ["ring_name", "height", "weight", "born", "birth_place", "trainer", "debut", "resides"]
#     wrt.writerow(header)
table = []
for link in links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    ring_name = soup.h2.text.strip()
    height = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Height") + div')
    if height is not None:
        height = height.text.strip()
    else:
        height = ""
    weight = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Weight") + div')
    if weight is not None:
        weight = weight.text.strip()
    else:
        weight = ""
    born = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Born") + div')
    if born is not None:
        born = born.text.strip()
    else:
        born = ""
    birth_place = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Birth Place") + div')
    if birth_place is not None:
        birth_place = birth_place.text.strip()
    else:
        birth_place = ""
    trainer = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Trainer") + div')
    if trainer is not None:
        trainer = trainer.text.strip()
    else:
        trainer = ""
    debut = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Debut") + div')
    if debut is not None:
        debut = debut.text.strip()
    else:
        debut = ""
    resides = soup.select_one('.pi-data-label:-soup-contains("Resides") + div')
    if resides is not None:
        resides = resides.text.strip()
    else:
        resides = ""
    table.append({
        'ring_name':ring_name,
        'height': weight,
        'born': born,
        'birth_place':birth_place,
        'trainer':trainer, 
        'debut':debut, 
        'resides':debut})

df = pd.DataFrame(table)#.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)#to save data in your local just uncomment
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
 ring_name            height  ...               debut             resides
0        Aaron Henare  231 lbs (105 kg)  ...   September 1, 2012   September 1, 2012
1       United Empire                    ...    October 16, 2020    October 16, 2020
2       Bad Luck Fale  344 lbs (156 kg)  ...       April 4, 2010       April 4, 2010
3         Bullet Club                    ...         May 3, 2013         May 3, 2013
4         Chase Owens   205 lbs (93 kg)  ...   February 17, 2007   February 17, 2007
..                ...               ...  ...                 ...                 ...
224        Yota Tsuji   200 lbs (91 kg)  ...      April 10, 2018      April 10, 2018
225       Yuji Nagata  238 lbs (108 kg)  ...  September 14, 1992  September 14, 1992
226  Yujiro Takahashi   198 lbs (90 kg)  ...       June 26, 2004       June 26, 2004
227       Yuya Uemura   180 lbs (82 kg)  ...      April 10, 2018      April 10, 2018
228   Zack Sabre, Jr.    180 lb (82 kg)  ...                2002                2002

[229 rows x 7 columns]
```